# contact DPST switch for dc inside door

Tags: switches

I want to put a LED inside a door and to get the current to the door I was trying to find a device that could conduct while the door is closed like so  https://www.ebay.com/itm/Two-Function-Magnum-Shooter-Dakota-Digital-MGS-2/231532017929?epid=1037725533&hash=item35e8623909:g:FU8AAOSwJTta1hxY:rk:7:pf:0

but I'm sure that there is something more specific(and cheap)then that, I just don't know what to search

Does anyone has an Idea?

Tanks

-------Edit------

Well, Sorry for the lack of information in the original post. My bad.
Here's the photo that's in the  link

[image: Switch]

The Purpose of this is that I want to do an electric locking for a bathroom door in my house and I want a LED to light everytime the locking system is switched on. I want the LED to be placed in the door itself(design preference) and to do that i'm looking for a way to "electrify" the door

Thats it

Comment: Please post enough information in your question so that we can understand it without following a link. Also note that the eBay link will die rendering your question useless to others in future. A photo is probably enough in this case. Tanks?

Comment: Sensing that a door is fully closed is different than almost closed.  What is the exact purpose?  To detect if opening 1mm or ??

Comment: Your link is to a variety of spring pin / pogo pin that is fairly short and squat and probably intended for routine usage in a consumer product, vs longer thin ones used for production test.  If you don't need the implicit switching, hinges with wires through them are a product.  In some cases some sort of inductive coupling could be interesting.

Comment: Taking a proven design from commonly available cars & vans - if the door is hinged, use a cable between the hinged side of the door and the door jam.  Only if the door is sliding, use the contact method as described.  But even then, many sliding car doors use a cable management system instead.

Comment: Google "power transfer hinge" for some useful products.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: I had a look at the ad and I think they are automotive parts similar to those seen on tailgates or sliding doors of vehicles. If they're like what I've seen on cars they're 6 mm diameter contacts so precision alignment isn't required. They're not pogo-pins. There is no drawing or datasheet, of course.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Well the idea coupled inductionis quite interesting. do have any idea on what and how should I search to find an appropriate product?
I saw a question that had a photo of something that would suite me perfect but I couldn't find it on the web
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/403624/minimal-components-for-lighting-an-led-via-wireless-power-transfer

Comment: @tristramit they're usually used for commercial structures, so they aren't too cheap, but a power transfer hinge will be vastly superior to alternatives.  If you can't afford one, it wouldn't be hard to use their design principles to make your own, although I'd want it to look nice, which may take some doing.  Obviously avoid running line voltage through the door and for the part that must flex, use appropriately rated cable, as finely stranded as possible, a bit oversized if possible, and armored (there are quite an assortment of armors you might use with varying finishes)

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of searches on google

Behold !

The "Tappet Contacts"!

[image: Tappet Contacts]

Comment: This is a modern version of devices used to power electric strikes in entry doors of apartment buildings. Placed by the top hinge, they maintain contact even if the  door is slightly open. Another choice is the metal shielded flexible cable. It looks like the metal cable on a pay-phone. They maintain contact at all door positions.